Verifying google authenticator key returning null
Some days ago it worked, but today it does not. I want to make a 2FA process through Google Authenticator with Laravel :
code of the image showing the QR code and the field holding the authenticator secret :
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ route('public.qrgen', ['text' => $google2fa]) }}" alt="">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="google2fa_secret" value="{{ $google2fa_secret }}">
<div class="input-item">
   <label for="google2fa_code">{{ __('Enter Google Authenticator Code') }}</label>
   <input id="google2fa_code" type="number" class="input-bordered" name="google2fa_code" placeholder="{{ __('Enter the Code to verify') }}">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Confirm 2FA') }}</button>

code of $google2fa :
use PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA;
...
public function account()
{
        $countries = $this->handler->getCountries();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userMeta = UserMeta::getMeta($user->id);

        $g2fa = new Google2FA();
        $google2fa_secret = $g2fa->generateSecretKey();
        $google2fa = $g2fa->getQRCodeUrl(
            site_info().'-'.$user->name,
            $user->email,
            $google2fa_secret
        );

    return view('user.account', compact('user', 'userMeta', 'countries', 'google2fa', 'google2fa_secret'));
}

code of the route public.qrgen source of the image displaying the QR code :
use QRCode;
...
public function qr_code(Request $request)
{
    $text = $request->get('text');
    if (empty($text)) {
        return abort(404);
    }
    return response(QRCode::text($text)->png(), 200)->header("Content-Type", 'image/png');
}

Here is the verification process code :
use PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA;
...
$user = User::FindOrFail(Auth::id());
if ($user) {
    // Google 2FA
    $ret['link'] = route('user.account');
    if (!empty($request->google2fa_code)) {
        $g2fa = new Google2FA();
        $verify = $g2fa->verifyKey($request->google2fa_secret, $request->google2fa_code);

        if ($verify) {
            $user->google2fa = $google2fa;
            $user->google2fa_secret = ($google2fa == 1 ? $request->google2fa_secret : null);
            $user->save();
            $ret['msg'] = 'success';
            $ret['message'] = __('Successfully '.($google2fa == 1 ? 'enable' : 'disable').' 2FA security in your account.');
        } else {
            $ret['msg'] = 'error';
            $ret['message'] = __('You have provide a invalid 2FA authentication code!');
        }
    } else {
        $ret['msg'] = 'warning';
        $ret['message'] = __('Please enter a valid authentication code!');
    }
}

At runtime $verify is null. So what is wrong ?

The function returns either bool or int, but not null. Can you double check?

@Raptor when I include the variable $verify inside the code $ret['message'] = __('You have provide a invalid 2FA authentication code!'); after I modified the code to $ret['message'] = "result of verify = $verify"; then I get result of verify = 

How about changing the code to $ret['message'] = var_export($verify, true);? Then you can truly know what's in the $verify. Anyways, in your case, since it does not print anything in the code, it represents false (although null value prints nothing as well, but the function will not return null, therefore it must be false).
